Google Ads Square Logo Not Filling Circle
I'm encountering an issue with Google Ads where the square logo I uploaded doesn't fill the circular space on the platform. Despite uploading a square logo as per the requirements, it appears smaller within a circular frame on Google Ads.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Uploaded a square logo (e.g., 512x512 pixels) through the Google Ads interface.
Checked the preview, and the logo appears smaller and doesn't fill the circular space properly.
Verified the dimensions and file format (PNG or JPEG) are correct according to Google Ads guidelines.

Is there a specific format or setting I'm missing to ensure that my square logo appears correctly within the circular frame on Google Ads? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.



Having the same exact issue and cannot find anything related online for fixing it. Tired different sizes, circle or square logo. My logo always gets zoomed out with white space to fill in the google image container

I made a square logo, at first it didn't recognize it as shown above, but after a couple of weeks Google applied the changes automatically and the logo is displayed correctly now.
